# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function X on Y

Tags: php

I am trying to learn OOP PHP so much of this is new to me. I have seen other posts but havent found one that answers my question.

```
class Test
{
  public function a(){
    //getting data...
    return $array;
  }
  public function b($array){
    return true;
  }
}


$test = new Test();
$x = $test->a()->b();
```

When I attempt the above I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function a() on array

Can someone explain why this doesnt work? `a` `returns` an `array` and `b` accepts an `array`.

Comment: `$x = $test->b($test->a());` is the correct syntax. What you are trying to do is called method chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you're trying to do here, you'd need to use this instead:

```
$x = $test->b($test->a());
```

The second arrow in the expression

```
$x = $test->a()->b();
```

attempts to call an object method on the return value of `$test->a()`, which is an array as you know. It does not pass the return value of `a()` as an argument to `b()`.

In order to use a syntax like `->a()->b()`, `a()` must return an object with a method `b()`. If the method `b()` is a method from the same object, you can do that by returning `$this` in `a()`, but if it also needs to return an array, that won't work, so you won't be able to chain the methods like this.

---

It is *possible* to make it work if `a()` doesn't return the array, but instead stores in in an object property, and `b()` doesn't take an array, but instead operates on the data in the property.

```
class Test
{
    protected $data;

    public function a() {
        //getting data...
        $this->data = $theDataYouGot;
        return $this;
    }

    public function b($array) {
        // do something with $this->data
        return true;
    }
}
```

Personally I try to avoid this sort of thing because I think it adds unnecessary complexity and makes testing more difficult without much added benefit, but I have seen it done.